# I can't test a contrast in my repeated-measures ANOVA in Stata 12. Why?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, stata

The anova command is

```
anova score method/subject|method prediction method#prediction / prediction#subject|method infdir method#infdir / infdir#subject|method prediction#infdir method#prediction#infdir if(agegroup==0 & block==1), repeated(prediction infdir)
```

where `method` is a between-subjects factor, and each level of `infdir` is nested in `prediction` (repeated within subjects: level 1 and 2 of `infdir` are prompted for each level of `prediction` within subjects, where each of those is between subjects in `method`).

I get the lovely ANOVA output I want that I've replicated in SPSS.

However, I cannot use the `contrast` function at all. It, `margins`, and similar functions all return `(not testable)` whenever I attempt to examine simple effects.

Does anyone know why?

Edit: For some reason I can't answer my own question in such a way that it counts as answered so other people can reference it later. I'll fix it, but until then:

I figured it out. I needed to add

```
emptycells(reweight)
```

After my `contrast` command. Empty cells in the interaction between the factors were throwing off the functions. I just had to RTFM more.

Comment: edit it back your question and post your own answer, so that others would see that the question is resolved.

Comment: [Why can't users with less than 100 reputation answer their own question sooner than 8 hours after asking?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123374/150510)